# Host a PHP Socket server program in AWS

Tags: php, sockets, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, udp

My requirement is to host a php socket server script in AWS EC2. and communicate to that socket server. This is what I have done so far but its not working.

**`server.php` script that acts a socket server and listens to clients:**

```
<?php
// set some variables
$host = "127.0.0.1";
$port = 53;

// don't timeout!
set_time_limit(0);

// create socket
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) or die("Could not create socket\n");

// bind socket to port
$result = socket_bind($socket, $host, $port) or die("Could not bind to socket\n");

// start listening for connections
$result = socket_listen($socket, 3) or die("Could not set up socket listener\n");

// accept incoming connections
// spawn another socket to handle communication
$spawn = socket_accept($socket) or die("Could not accept incoming connection\n");

// read client input
$input = socket_read($spawn, 1024) or die("Could not read input\n");

// clean up input string
$input = trim($input);

echo "Client Message : ".$input;
// reverse client input and send back

$output = strrev($input) . "\n";
socket_write($spawn, $output, strlen ($output)) or die("Could not write output\n");

// close sockets
socket_close($spawn);
socket_close($socket);
```

**In AWS security group, I have added following Inbound rule**:

[image]

- I run the server,php script from SSH using command "php server.php".
- I tried to connect to the server from SocketTest tool where I entered following
  value

> **host**: 52.xx.xx.xxx (masked the actual value here) and **port**: 53

I am not able to connect to the socket server. It would be really helpful if someone can guide me if I am missing anything here

Please note that same server.php program is working fine when tested in local xampp server

Comment: Is the connection being timed out? Does the problem still persist if you accept all inbound protocols on all ports in your security group?

Comment: The connection getting timed out. Can you help me out how to accept all inbound protocols on all ports in security group?

Comment: Security Groups -> Select your security group -> click Edit -> Type: All traffic -> Protocol: All -> Port range: 0-65535 -> Source: Anywhere and 0.0.0.0/0. Of course, please bear in mind that it's only for debugging. You shouldn't have set that in production.

Comment: I added the new inbound rule. Now Connection getting refused

Comment: Are you sure `SocketTest` (whatever that may be?) is making an UDP connection and not a TCP connection?

Comment: Thanks Defozo and Martjin. Its working now. I have made small change to my script. Used instance's private IP instead of 127.0.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

You have used '127.0.0.1' as host in server script.
You have to replace it with your server's private IP address.